# Apple Aluminum Keyboard Via Bluetooth - Fn Key Problem

Tags: bluetooth, lubuntu, apple, xmodmap

I'm connecting an Apple Bluetooth Aluminum keyboard ([this one](http://www.apple.com/keyboard/)) to my Lubuntu setup using the `blueman` applet.

The keyboard types fine, but I would like to use its `fn` key to change screen brightness changing, page-up (fn+ctrl+down), page-down (fn+ctrl+up), et cetera. Right now the `fn` key doesn't seem to work.

When I use `xev`, I don't see anything happen when I press `fn`.

Does the keyboard not send this to the computer at all?

Do I need to configure `blueman`'s "Input Service" setting to make this an Apple (rather than a generic) keyboard? (It's not obvious how to do this.)

Is `xev` just not showing the `fn` key?

Where in this stack of software do I need to make a change to achieve the desired behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the program gnome-bluetooth. It can be installed through the software center.

Comment: @William, I have installed it via `sudo apt-get install gnome-bluetooth`. It is unclear to me how to run it since calling `gnome-bluetooth` from the command line tells me the command is not found.

Comment: @William, I found the applet under bluetooth-applet. Unfortunately, it didn't solve any of my problems.

Comment: Okay, sorry I can't be of any more help.